# In stock products only in my search custom code

Tags: magento-1, custom, search

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('author')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('author', array('like' => $searchstring.'%'))
    ->setPage($pageid, $resultcount);
```

above given is my search custom code. Please let me know how to only add in stock product using the above code.

Comment: what version of Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code at the end of the line.

Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('author')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('author', array('like' => $searchstring.'%'))
    ->setPage($pageid, $resultcount);
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
```

Thanks